# Is it appropriate to ask a question in an answer, or should this be a comment?

Tags: discussion, answer-format, questions

I answered this question: [Whenever I try to download my Ubuntu 1 files, chrome block me.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485150/whenever-i-try-to-download-my-ubuntu-1-files-chrome-block-me/485151#485151)

And Raphael commented that this could be a comment. (Not accusing, just wanting to know for sure).

Is this a suitable answer, or would it be better as a comment, as this is part of the problem finding process?
I know that comments should not be used as a discussion, but I don't know how to avoid this  when the user doesn't have enough rep to chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably on the line.

It doesn't suggest why there's a problem or confirm that it's a problem with a specific browser. If you did this, it would be a much better answer... But it's certainly on its way there.

But I'm saying that with context. I know that on a technical level Chrome likes to block things it considers suspicious. "Try another browser" isn't always going to be a relevant answer though it might be a good debugging point, which would make it a better comment in those cases.

In this specific case (because somebody's just trying to get something done, with a looming time constraint) suggesting the use of the default browser isn't a bad idea... Just explain why it's likely to work and you'll be well into answer territory.

You could also develop the idea about transferring them to another cloud repo. I don't know how one would do that without first downloading them.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to check it.

Comment: I myself, would have put it in a comment, but what Oli says is right.

Comment: @Seth, So it really can go either way depending on opinions. I'll improve the answer!

Comment: I think both Oli and Seth are right.  I would have split it as a comment AND an answer.  The comment being try another browser, and the answer being just use mover.io.